# CSS Elastic textbox

Tags: css, textbox, elasticlayout

My requirement is this.
I need a text box with a width of 5px. As I type something on it the width should be increased. Is it possible to do using CSS only without js

thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ATM this is not possible with CSS only.

To achieve this you would have to check the current content width of the textfield on every keystroke in it (use the `onKeyUp` event of it) and then change the textbox' width accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

hmm i only know like this one..

```
<script language="javascript">
function expand_textbox(s)
{
    s.size = s.size + 1;
}
</script>

<input type="text" size="20" name=txt onkeyup="expand_textbox(this)" >
```

try it..

Comment: Notice that that will not really work nicely if you delete some text and then start writing again...